# Using the Zoho Inventory API can you set the item to Track Inventory and Track Serial Number

Tags: json, api, inventory, zoho

I'm using the [https://inventory.zoho.com/api/v1/items/{item_id}?organization_id={orgid}](https://inventory.zoho.com/api/v1/items/%7Bitem_id%7D?organization_id=%7Borgid%7D) endpoint to update an item. It seems that the information about the inventory tracking hasn't made it to the API yet.

Does anyone have a work around or is this just how Zoho is and I have to wait for V2?

[image: The fields in Zoho]

Comment: It might help include an example of the code  POSTing to the endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

These are the fields missing from the documentation:
track_serial_number (boolean value), track_batch_number (boolean value).

One of them can be true and to disable tracking set both of them to false.

An example request with Serial Number Tracking enabled for multiple warehouses:

```
{
   "name":"Sample Item",
   "description":"",
   "rate":1,
   "account_id":"2181652000000000300",
   "item_id":"2181652000010372000",
   "tax_id":"",
   "tags":[
      
   ],
   "sku":"",
   "upc":"",
   "ean":"",
   "part_number":"",
   "isbn":"",
   "custom_fields":[
      {
         "value":"",
         "customfield_id":"2181652000000076139"
      }
   ],
   "purchase_rate":2,
   "purchase_account_id":"2181652000000034003",
   "purchase_description":"",
   "item_type":"inventory",
   "is_taxable":true,
   "tax_exemption_code":"",
   "product_type":"goods",
   "reorder_level":"1",
   "vendor_id":"2181652000002237000",
   "inventory_account_id":"2181652000000034000",
   "track_serial_number":true,
   "track_batch_number":false,
   "brand":"",
   "manufacturer":"",
   "is_returnable":true,
   "category_id":"",
   "package_details":{
      "length":"",
      "width":"",
      "height":"",
      "weight":"",
      "weight_unit":"lb",
      "dimension_unit":"in"
   },
   "warehouses":[
      {
         "warehouse_id":"2181652000000076392",
         "initial_stock":"2",
         "initial_stock_rate":"3"
      }
   ],
   "unit":"box"
}
```